# Calling this.$super in an extended component (sw-url-field) throws a TypeError

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

I need an URL field, exactly like Shopware's `sw-url-field`, but it should **not** automatically remove the trailing slash.

My Shopware version is 6.5.7.3.

So in my custom plugin I am creating a new component `my-url-field` and overwriting the `sw-url-field`'s `validateCurrentValue` method:

```
const {Component} = Shopware;

Component.extend('my-url-field', 'sw-url-field', {
    methods: {
        validateCurrentValue(value) {
            return this.$super('validateCurrentValue', value);
        }
    }
});
```

Even without having any custom logic implemented (like in the code above), the following JavaScript error is thrown in the Shopware Administration after pasting an URL (example `http://localhost/Category/`) into the field and leaving it (blur):

```
An error was captured in current module: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bind')
    at a.$super (async-component.factory.ts:649:9)
    at a.validateCurrentValue (index.js:6:32)
    at a.checkInput (index.js:134:20)
    at a.value (index.js:104:5)
    at Cn (vue.esm.js:3736:25)
    at e.run (vue.esm.js:4252:82)
    at on (vue.esm.js:3241:30)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vue.esm.js:3864:37)
    at In (vue.esm.js:3805:12)
```

Further, the leading `http://` is not removed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SCrz.png)
The value of the field is `http://localhost/Category`.
I expect it to be `localhost/Category`.

When I add more logic to the example above like this:

```
const {Component} = Shopware;

Component.extend('my-url-field', 'sw-url-field', {
    methods: {
        validateCurrentValue(value) {
            const trailingSlash = value.search(/\/+$/) > -1 ? '/' : '';
            const sanitizedValue = this.$super('validateCurrentValue', value);
            
            return sanitizedValue ? sanitizedValue + trailingSlash : sanitizedValue;
        }
    }
});
```

And I build the administration JS as usual and refresh the page in Shopware Admin. After pasting the same URL to the field and leaving it, the same JavaScript error occurs and the value in the field is `http://localhost/Category/`. So my custom logic is executed, but actually I expect the value to be `localhost/Category/`.

Any help highly appreciated!